# How do launch experiments in DVC?

Tags: python, dvc

I want to launch some experiments in DVC. But when I set values of experiment parameters, DVC deletes file 'params.yaml', and experiment doesn't set in queue.

Simplified code for example:
Python file 'test.py':

```
import numpy as np
import json
import yaml

params = yaml.safe_load(open('params.yaml'))["test"]

precision = np.random.random()
recall = params['value']
accuracy = np.random.random()
 

rows = {'precision': precision,
        'recall': recall,
        'accuracy': accuracy}


with open(params['metrics_path'], 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(rows, outfile)

fpr = 10*np.random.random((1,10)).tolist()
tpr = 10*np.random.random((1,10)).tolist()

with open('plot.json', 'w') as outfile2:
    json.dump(
      {
        "roc": [ {"fpr": f, "tpr": t} for f, t in zip(fpr, tpr) ]
      }, 
      outfile2
      )
```

params.yaml:

```
test:
  metrics_path: "scores.json"
  value: 1
```

dvc.yaml:

```
stages:
  test:
    cmd: python test.py
    deps:
    - test.py
    params:
    - test.metrics_path
    - test.value
    metrics:
    - scores.json:
        cache: false
    plots:
    - plot.json:
        cache: false
        x: fpr
        y: tpr
```

It is strange behavior. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce it. what version of `dvc` are you using? ( output from `dvc doctor`) It runs as expect when I run `dvc exp run -S test.value=2` and the result from 
`dvc exp show` is also correct.

Comment: DVC version: 2.10.2
Command ```dvc exp run -S test.value=2``` works correctly on my computer too. But when I try to use command ```dvc exp run --queue -S test.value=101``` to put experiment in queue, DVC deletes file 'params.yaml'.

Comment: And then after using command ```dvc exp run --run-all``` I get error message:

ERROR: 'dvc.yaml' does not exist                                                                
ERROR: Failed to reproduce experiment '5920339'

But this file exists (in the current directory, where DVC project was initialized)!

Comment: Sorry, still can not reproduce it. Are you in a clean repo?

Comment: There are only script, metrics files, dvc and git files in folder with dvc project: 
```
/Documents/temp$ ls
dvc.lock  dvc.yaml  params.yaml  plot.json  scores.json  test.py
```
(I use this simple project for example, but I have same problem in my another big project) What do you mean for "clean repo"?

Comment: @AlimagadovK. for now you can `git add params.yaml` (no need to `git commit`) before each `dvc exp run --queue` so it doesn't get deleted, but this may indeed be a bug... Feel free to open a report directly in https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues !

Comment: @Jorge Orpinel Pérez, Thank you! File 'params.yaml' doesn't delete if command ```git add params.yaml``` was called before, but command ```dvc exp run --run-all``` still not working. I get message ```ERROR: 'dvc.yaml' does not exist``` with this file located in the current dvc-project directory. I have reported about strange behavior for ```dvc exp run --queue```, but now I need to launch 'run-all' for queue. Maybe, is it possible to do it in some way?

Comment: `dvc.yaml` has to be in Git too. Queued experiments only see files and changes that are committed (or at least Git-staged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It is necessary, that all files (executable scripts, 'dvc.yaml', 'params.yaml') be tracked by git. In this case `dvc exp run` command works correctly.